# How is fseek() implemented in the filesystem?

Tags: performance, architecture, filesystems, fseek

This is not a pure programming question, however it impacts the performance of programs using fseek(), hence it is important to know how it works. A little disclaimer so that it doesn't get closed.

I am wondering how efficient it is to insert data in the middle of the file. Supposing I have a file with 1MB data and then I insert something at the 512KB offset. How efficient would that be compared to appending my data at the end of the file? Just to make the example complete lets say I want to insert 16KB of data.

I understand the answer varies depending on the filesystem, however I assume that the techniques used in common filesystems are quite similar and I just want to get the right notion of it.

Comment: Using fseek() et al you simply cannot insert data in the middle of a file, so your question is moot.

Comment: You can simply not insert data in the middle of a file (as much as you cannot delete something from the beginning or the middle of a file). The best you can do is overwriting data in the middle of a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(disclaimer: I want just to add some hints to this interesting discussion)
IMHO there are some things to take into account:

1) fseek is not a primary system service, but a library function. To evaluate its performance we must consider how the file stream library is implemented. In general, the file I/O library adds a layer of buffering in user space, so the performance of fseek may be quite different if the target position is inside or outside the current buffer. Also, the system services that the I/O libary uses may vary a lot. I.e. on some systems the library uses extensively the file memory mapping if possible.

2) As you said, different filesystems may behave in a very different way. In particular, I would expect that a transactional filesystem must do something very smart and perhaps expensive to be prepared to a possible rollback of an aborted write operation in the middle of a file.

3) Modern OS'es have very aggressive caching algorithms. An "fseeked" file is likely to be already present in cache, so operations become much faster. But they may degrade a lot if the overall filesystem activity produced by other processes become important.

Any comments?

Comment: Of course, inserting is in generalmore expensive than appending because to insert, at least, one must also move the previous content, i.e. append to the end of the file! But the interesting part of Pajton's question is about fseek operation performaces. Any comment?

Answer (score 4):

Let us assume the ext2 FS and the Linux OS as an example.  I don't think there will be a significant performance difference between a insert and an append.  In both cases the files node and offset table must be read, the relevant disk sector mapped into memory, the data updated and at some later point the data written back to disk.  What will make a big performance difference in this example is good temporal and spatial locality when accessing parts of the file since this will reduce the number of load/store combos.

As a previous answers says you may be able to speed up both operations if you deal with data writes that exact multiples of the FS block size, in this case you could skip the load stage and just insert the new blocks into the files inode datastrucure.  This would not be practical, as you would need low level access to the FS driver, and using it would be very restrictive and not portable.

Answer (score 4):

`fseek(...)` is a library call, not an OS system call. It is the run-time library that takes care of the actual overhead involved in making a system call to the OS, technically speaking, fseek is indirectly making a call to the system but really it is not (this brings up a clear distinction between the differences between a library call and a system call). `fseek(...)` is a standard input-output function regardless of the underlying system...however...and this is a big *however*...

The OS will more than likely to have cached the file in its kernel memory, that is, the direct offset to the location on the disk on where the 1's and 0's are stored, it is through the OS's kernel layers, more than likely, a top-most layer within the kernel that would have the snapshot of what the file is composed of, i.e. data irrespectively of what it contains (it does not care either way, as long as the 'pointers' to the disk structure for that offset to the lcoation on the disk is valid!)...

When `fseek(..)` occurs, there would be a lot of over-head, indirectly, the kernel delegated the task of reading from the disk, depending on how fragmented the file is, it could be theoretically, "all over the place", that could be a significant over-head in terms of having to, from a user-land perspective, i.e. the C code doing an `fseek(...)`, it could be scattering itself all over the place to gather the data into a "one contiguous view of the data" and henceforth, inserting into the middle of a file, (remember at this stage, the kernel would have to adjust the location/offsets into the actual disk platter for the data) would be deemed slower than appending to the end of the file.

The reason is quite simple, the kernel "knows" what was the last offset was, and simply wipe the EOF marker and insert more data, behind the scenes, the kernel, is having to allocate another block of memory for the disk-buffer with the adjusted offset to the location on the disk following an EOF marker, once the appending of data is completed.

Comment: Good hint, the data scattering may be an important cause of bad performance. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One observation I have made about `fseek` on Solaris, is that each call to it resets the read buffer of the `FILE`. The next read will then always read a full block (8K by default). So if you have a lot of random access with small reads it's a good idea to do it unbuffered (`setvbuf` with `NULL` buffer) or even use direct syscalls (`lseek`+`read` or even better `pread` which is only 1 syscall instead of 2). I suppose this behaviour will be similar on other OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert data to the middle of file efficiently only if data size is a multiple of FS sector but OSes doesn't provide such functions so you have to use low-level interface to the FS driver.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting data in the middle of the file is less efficient than appending to the end because when inserting you would have to move the data after the insertion point to make room for the data being inserted. Moving these data would involve reading them from disk, writing the data to be inserted and then writing the old data after the inserted data. So you have at least one extra read and write when inserting.